# Can't catch custom Exception from other file and closure

Tags: groovy

I have two Groovy-Script files, one declares a class (extends Exception) and gets included into the other file.
In the other file I want to catch my custom exception, but I can't catch it.

To include one file into the other, I am using `evaluate(new File(sourceDir, filename)` and closures to declare callable methods.

I expect to catch my PlayException and print 'HURRA', but instead I just get a error message telling me, my code has thrown a PlayException.

I want to keep the class inside the Groovy-Scrpit-File and I don't want to move it to a separate Groovy-Class-File, because the class is only needed in this script.

playMe.groovy

```
class PlayException extends Exception {
    PlayException() {
        super()
    }
}

play = {
    throw new PlayException()
}
```

rockMe.groovy

```
evaluate(new File("/path/to/folder", 'playMe.groovy'))

void runMe() {
    try {
        play()
    } catch(PlayException e) {
        println("HURRA!!") // Can't catch the error
    }
}

runMe()
```

Error Message

```
Caught: PlayException
PlayException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at playMe$_run_closure1.doCall(playMe.groovy:8)
    at playMe$_run_closure1.doCall(playMe.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at rockMe.runMe(rockMe.groovy:5)
    at rockMe.run(rockMe.groovy:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```